# regex capture first float after know string

Tags: regex

i need to capture the first float after a known string within a string of floats and characters.

EG:

```
EU 1.5 UK 2.5 US 3.5
```

So I would like to capture *1.5* or *2.5*, with just the EU or 2.5 for detection.

```
(?<=EU)
```

Examples

I want to be able to capture the 1.5 after EU only by knowing that EU is the first string before it.

Comment: What are you asking about? Whether you can use a lookbehind in your regex pattern? Perhaps, it depends on the regex flavor. What did you try and what is the problem?

Comment: Since you are asking if it is possible, yes it is

Comment: Add few examples and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
([^EU ^US ^UK]+)
```

[Live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/6HowGS/1)

- Match a single character not present in the list below [^EU ^US ^UK]+
- + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- EU ^US ^UK matches a single character in the list EU ^SK (case
  sensitive)

Even better, if you are absolutely positive about the structure of the above string, you can skip all text this way:

```
([^A-Za-z ]+)
```

Comment: I think frank's problem is to find the number directly following a given String. So if the string is `EU` the expression could be `EU ([0-9.]*) `and would find `1.5`; if the string is `UK` the expression `UK ([0-9.]*) ` would find `2.5`.

Comment: Well thanks, let's see if he adds more details (e.g. the strings meaningful to him, like EU).

Answer (score 0):

If lookbehind is supported, you could use `(?<=EU )` (with a whitespace).

[`(?<=EU )[0-9]*\.[0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/A3iCGS/2)

You could also Match EU and capture the float in a capturing group:

[`EU ([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/fRlLQI/1)

**Explanation**

```
EU       # Match EU and a whitespace
(        # Capturing group
  [0-9]* # Match a digit zero or more times
  \.     # Match a dot
  [0-9]+ # Match a ditig one or more times
)        # Close capturing group
```

Comment: `(?<=US)([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)` Works though I need it to allow for possible white spaces, eg : https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/6

Comment: @frankastin What exactly needs to contains whitespaces? That example does not contain a float. You could add more examples to your question.

Comment: @frankastin What exactly needs to contain whitespaces? You added the same text with a capturing group. Do you mean [like this](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/1322)?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.  Now I need to get a book on Regex.